# My brush won't work again after I update the histogram in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I create a default histogram first and create an update function for it because the histogram need to interact with other charts. I successfully created the brush in the default chart, however when I use the same method in the update function it won't work, and it can't even print the debug message inside the brushed function.

```
function updateBarChart(filteredData) {
    console.log("update bar chart");

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(filteredData, function(d) { return +d.Age })])
        .range([0, bar_width]);

    var bin = d3.histogram()
        .domain(xScale.domain())
        .value(function (d) { return +d.Age; })
        .thresholds(100);

    var binData = bin(filteredData);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(binData, function (d) { return d.length; })])
        .range([bar_height, 0])
        .nice();

    // Update the X-axis
    barSvg.select(".x-axisBar")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

    // Update the Y-axis
    barSvg.select(".y-axisBar")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

    // Select the existing 'bars' group
    var barG = barSvg.select(".bars");

    // If the 'bars' group doesn't exist, create it
    if (barG.empty()) {
        console.log('check')
        barG = barSvg.append("g").classed("bars", true);
    }

    var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [bar_width, bar_height]])
    .on("start", brushed)
    .on("brush", brushed)
    .on("end", endbrushed);

    barG.call(brush);

    // Update and enter bars
    var rects = barG.selectAll("rect")
        .data(binData);

    rects.enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.x0))
        .attr("y", bar_height) // Initial position for enter selection
        .attr(
            "width",
            (d) => d3.max([0, xScale(d.x1) - xScale(d.x0)]) - 1
            )
    .attr("height", 0) // Initial height for enter selection
    .merge(rects)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.x0))
    .attr("width", (d) => d3.max([0, xScale(d.x1) - xScale(d.x0)]) - 1)
    .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.length))
    .attr("height", (d) => bar_height - yScale(d.length));

    // Remove old bars
    rects.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("y", bar_height)  // Move exit bars to the top
        .attr("height", 0)      // Set the height to 0
        .remove();

    function brushed() {

        console.log("brushed")
        
        extent = d3.event.selection;
    
        rects.classed("bar_selected", function (d) {
            return extent[0] <= xScale(d.x1) && extent[1] >= xScale(d.x0);
        });

        rects.classed("bar_unselected", function (d) {
            return extent[0] >= xScale(d.x1) || extent[1] <= xScale(d.x0);
        });
        
    }

    function endbrushed(){
        extent = d3.event.selection;

        // Check if there is a selection
        if (!extent) {
            isBrushed = 0;
            // Remove the "bar_selected" and "bar_unselected" classes
            rects.classed("bar_selected", false);
            rects.classed("bar_unselected", false);

        }               
    }

}
```